# wired connection between raspberry pi and android app

Tags: python, connection, java, android, data-transfer

I am reading Can data with Pcan, and I am transferring my Can data to my Raspberry Pi 4. With this code

```python
import can 
import serial

# CAN bus setup
can_bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype="pcan", channel="PCAN_USBBUS1", bitrate=9600)

# Serial port setup
ser = serial.Serial("ttySO", baudrate=9600)

while True:
    # Read from CAN bus
    received_msg = can_bus.recv()

    if received_msg.arbitration_id == 0x18904001:
        data_byte = received_msg.data[0]
        inst_voltage = ((received_msg.data[2] << 8) | received_msg.data[3]) / 10
        soc = received_msg.data[4]

        # Print CAN data
        print("CAN - Instant Voltage: {:.1f} V, SOC: {}%".format(inst_voltage, soc))

    # Read from serial port
    if ser.isOpen() and ser.in_waiting > 0:
        serial_data = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        print("Serial - Received:", serial_data)
```

I am trying to transfer that data to my Android app. I was stuck on the connection between the Raspberry Pi and the Android device. My Android device doesn't see the Raspberry Pi. What is wrong here? By the way, I can only use a wired connection. ( I prefer USB )

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What do you want to achieve at the end? What are the Raspberry Pi and the Android device supposed to do? Why don't you do everything on the Raspberry Pi? What kind of data do you want to transfer? How is it related to CAN or PCAN?

Comment: In your edit you added "Arduino". Is this a third device in your (planned) setup? Or did you confuse Android and Arduino? As I understand the code, it reads a CAN message, prints signal values if the ID matches a value, reads from a serial port and prints the received data. I don't see any relation to an Android app or an Arduino. Do I understand right that you connected a PCAN interface to your Raspberry Pi and that the Python program will run on the Pi? If you don't clarify my questions I cannot help.

Comment: Sorry sir u right. I write wrong. Yes my setup is reading CAN message from pcan device on raspberry pi. Python program will read the CAN message and then print that data to my android app(battery soc app ).  My setup  is android Tablet, Raspberry pi, pcan, usb cable.

Comment: Please add all requested information or clarification to the question. It is still unclear why you want to use the Android app instead of doing all/most of the work on the Raspberry Pi. Why are you restricted to a wired connection? It would be much easier to provide the data by some machine-readable protocol via a HTTP(S) connection via WiFi or maybe bluetooth.

Comment: Hello ı am working on ev car project for my universty. And ı am responsible of multimedia of car. I need CAN data on my multimedia. I am reading car battery soc and some of datas. I make an android app for battery. And ı am controling my car air conditioner. So ı need communication between multimedia ( android tablet)- CAN LINE. At the begining on the project ı was doing this with arduino and mcp2515 module and it works fine. But we are try use raspberry pi 4  ( bcs we wanna lose multiple cards). I can read CAN datas on raspberry. With my python code. But ı cant send that data to my tablet.

Comment: Now ı am wondering can is this possiable to send data raspberry to android whit usb serial. Sorry ı missed your quastion. I must use serial comminacte bcs of my multimedia (android tablet) has can run apple car play. So ı cant use blutooth. ( I think ?)

Comment: **Please don't use comments to provide requested information or clarification. [Edit] your question instead.** Why don't you use WiFi?

Comment: If the main point of the question is how to use a wired serial connection on an Android tablet, then it is off-topic on this site.

Comment: I cant use wifi bcs ıf ı connect wifi or bluetooth ı cant connect phone. I used this topic because ı can  a wired serial connection on an Android tablet with arduino. But ı dont want use arduino. Because ı have a Raspberry Pi on car and ı am trying lose other cards. I am really newbie on the blogs sorry about my mistakes.

Comment: All explanation of your use case belongs to the question. But I don't understand it. You wrote "I used this topic because ı can a wired serial connection on an Android tablet with arduino." Do I understand right that you can communicate between Android tablet and Arduino via serial connection? If yes, describe the communication protocol **in your question**. Then we might be able to help you to implement this for Raspberry Pi. What do you mean with "ıf ı connect wifi or bluetooth ı cant connect phone"? How is a phone related to your setup of tablet and Pi? Please clarify in your question.

Comment: @Alper you have been asked to edit your question with the information ... what is preventing you from doing that? ... you responded to the question about the WiFi ... that indicates that you read the comment